# Replacing a spring-boot-starter-parent by a spring-boot-starter + spring-boot-dependencies: it compiles but doesn't run integration tests anymore

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

All the 60 modules of my project are using a parent POM, based on `Spring-boot 2.7.14`

- that runs JUnit 5 tests (without starting *Spring-Boot*) when running a `mvn install`
- and `integration-test` on launched (during tests) *Spring-Boot* servers, when running a `mvn install -Passemblage`

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.14</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Construction normale -->
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>

            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <properties>
                <!-- Tests unitaires activés par défaut, et tests d'intégration désactivés -->
                <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Construction avec tests d'assemblage -->
        <profile>
            <id>assemblage</id>

            <properties>
                <!-- Tests unitaires et tests d'intégration activés en Intégration -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Plugin Failsafe : exécution de tests d'intégration -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>integration-test</id>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin Surefire : exécution tests unitaires -->
            <!-- Tous les tests sauf ceux débutant par IT* -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</project>
```

It works conveniently.
But the event is that I have to exclude few modules from that building, that must be built before the existence of *Spring-Boot* is known.

Until today, I had for module compilation: `<POM Parent>, A, B, C, D...`
and now I will have: `<POM Parent>, A, B, <POM declaring Spring-Boot>, C, D...`

Therefore, I cannot declare `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.14` for parent anymore.

---

1. I removed `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.14` declaration
2. I've added for dependency: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.14`
3. And in dependency management: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.14` with `import` scope.

It still compiles the project.

But my issue is that a `mvn install -Passemblage` do not start *Spring-Boot* `integration-test` anymore (and a `mvn integration-test -Passemblage` has also no effect).

Answer (score 0):

For Integration-test execution, you should use `maven-failsafe-plugin` instead of `maven-surefire-plugin`.

You didn't specify the goal.

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: `maven-failsafe-plugin` is the one used during integration tests (when the parameter `skip.integration.tests` = `false`)